# Add software restriction policies programmatically using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, gpo

Need to block user to install the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari) in the machines which are in the domain.

For restrict application, we can add the binary name in the below registry. But this method is not working to restrict the browser installation.

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun
```

We can restrict installation if we add the details in 'Software Restriction Policies' in the GPO but unable to add the details programmatically in the machine using Powershell. We got an option to use IGroupPolicyObject interface with C++ examples but no details available in Powershell.

Comment: Does this help? https://rattanconsulting.com/2017/05/17/block-google-chrome-installation/

Comment: @NekoMusume, Thanks for your comment. It’s having the details to add the software details manually but we need to add programmatically using Powershell